# GWT custom widget. getStyleElement().getPropertyString returns null

Tags: java, css, gwt

I am trying to write a Composite widget :

```
public class SpectrumData extends Composite {

   public SpectrumData(...) {
     verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
     initWidget(verticalPanel);
     this.setStyleName("spectrumData");
     String maxcolor = this.getStyleElement().getPropertyString("max-color");
     // Here maxcolor is null 
     ...
   }
```

}

And here is my css:

```
.spectrumData {
     scale: 4;
     min-color: #0000ff;
     max-color: #ff0000;
  }
```

I checked the style sheet was properly included in the HTML :

So why does my getPropertyString return null?

Thank you in advance for any clues.

Ranga

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of those CSS properties. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`getStyleElement()` returns the inline style for the element, not the computed style. So, if you wrap an element that looks like `<div style="max-color: #ff0000"></div>`, then you should be able get the max-color from the style element. `setStyleName()` only sets the `class` attribute of the element.

Comment: Not sure I follow. This would be something you put in your html. First I don't know where I would place this in the html. Would I nest this in the <td..></td> element where I want the spectrum browser to go? What I would really like is to place the max-color etc. properties in CSS and to read the value from the CSS. How can I do that? I could possibly just place it in a separate XML file and parse that but I want to do things in the right way. Thanks!